# eager loading in recursive partial ( Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, lazy-loading

I have a model with a self-join:

```
  class Audience < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :children, class_name: "Audience", foreign_key: "parent_id"
   belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Audience"
  end
```

It is a simple tree structure that is arbitrary levels deep.

I have been recursively printing out a form using a  partial (_checkbox_for_children.html.erb) like so:

Starting with ( with the knowledge of root audience):

```
<%= render 'checkbox_for_children', :audience => root_audience %>
```

And the Partial itself(checkbox_for_children) looks like follows:

```
<% children = audience.children %>

<ul class="list-unstyled">
  <% children.each do |child| %>
    <li>
      <% if child.targetable.present? %>
        <%= check_box_tag("demographic_data[#{child.name}]", child.demographic_id) %>
        <%= child.name %>
        <% if child.children.present? %>
           <%= render 'checkbox_for_children', :audience => child %>
        <% end %>
      <% else %>
        <%= child.name %>
        <% if child.children.present? %>
           <%= render 'checkbox_for_children', :audience => child %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

The problem with this approach is that way too many queries are being run to render a view. I need to eagerload children somehow to manage the number of queries. Any ideas?

I don't think I can just pass in includes(:children) via the local variable of the partial ( I tried, it throws an error).

The controller is quite simple and just looks like this:

```
  def add_demographic
    @relevant_providers = Provider.have_audience
    render "add_demographic"
  end
```

provider has_many audiences which has many children ( in the audience table itself)